# Как передать name и из JSON в JS объект?

Tags: javascript, json

Имею такую структуру JSON

```
[
  { "name": "foo",
    "status": "success" }, {
    "name": "bar",
    "status": "success"}, {
    "name": "biz",
    "status": "success"
  }
]
```

Нужно выбрать все значения полей name.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [
  { "name": "foo", "status": "success" }, 
  { "name": "bar", "status": "success" }, 
  { "name": "biz", "status": "success" }
];

var res = data.map(item => { return { name: item.name }; });
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: А ничего, что все же изначально это JSON? Я бы сделал `data` строкой и распарсил бы JSON для начала.

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы в итоге я получил не один массив name, а 
{"name": "foo"}, {"name": "bar"}, {"name": "biz"} ?

Comment: чтобы еще красивее `data.map(({name})=>({name}))` :)